# Strange Error when Unit Testing a particular function in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I'm working on this [Exercise 49 in Learn Ruby the Hard Way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex49.html)

The exercise asks to write a unit test for each function provided. One of the unit tests I am writing is giving me an error.

Here is the code I am testing (word_list is an array of Pair structs)

```
Pair = Struct.new(:token, :word)

def peek(word_list)
    begin
        word_list.first.token
    rescue
        nil
    end
end

def match(word_list, expecting)
    begin
        word = word_list.shift
        if word.token == expecting
            word
        else
            nil
        end
    rescue
        nil
    end
end

def skip(word_list, token)
    while peek(word_list) == token
        match(word_list, token)
    end
end
```

Here is the test:

```
def test_skip
    small_list = [Pair.new(:verb, 'go'), Pair.new(:verb, 'do')]
    skip(small_list, :verb)
    assert_equal([],small_list) 
end
```

Here is the error I get when I run the unit test:

```
  1) Error:
test_skip(SentenceTests):
TypeError: backtrace must be Array of String
    test_sentence.rb:23:in `test_skip'
```

In this case, line 23 refers to "skip(small_list, :verb)". I am not sure why this error is happening, the above two functions were unit tested as well and those tests came out fine.

@Zabba, I did put them exactly as specified in the exercise above:

```
class ParserError < Exception

end
```

If anyone needs to see the exact files I am using here is the link to a gist:
https://gist.github.com/1190148

Comment: Remove the `rescue` clause from `match` and `peek`, one at a time, and see what exception you get if any.

Comment: I removed rescue from match and peek, one at a time, and still got the same error in all cases.

Comment: Are you using `ParserError` or calling `raise` anywhere?

Comment: What if you remove all the stuff after `raise` wherever it is being used .. do you still get that error?

Comment: What else is involved here? How exactly are you running this code? There is a `backtrace` method on Exception and that's supposed to return an Array.

Comment: You can view the full code on the link provided above. My file is exactly the same. For the sake of clarity, I only provided functions/code directly relevant to this particular test.

Comment: How does the test code look like?

Comment: You can see the complete files in a gist link I added above.

Comment: If you now reintroduce the `rescue` part in `peek` it works. `word_list.first` is finally `nil` and then `nil.token` raises an exception. Still I don't get why you see such a strange error message. Which Ruby version are you using?

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

Comment: @Andrew Barinov: See the update to my answer. Please note that the other point is still valid.

Comment: Should we introduce a tag for "Learn Ruby The Hard Way", like we have for Ruby Koans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
skip(small_list, :verb)
```

makes your test skip through the whole list (2 verbs). Finally, it is empty.
So `small_list.first`is `nil` which has no method/field `word`.

I get the error

```
undefined method `word' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

though.

Probably in your code this exception is caught by some other code which itself raises the exception you are seeing.

**UPDATE**

It turns out in Ruby 1.9's test/unit (more specifically in the minitest/unit it is based on), there is a method `skip` which collides with your `skip`. See [minitest/unit.rb](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/unit.rb), line 610. That method raised the exception because it expected its 2nd parameter to be an array.

Just rename your `skip`.

Comment: `def test_skip`
  `small_list = [Pair.new(:verb, 'go'), Pair.new(:verb, 'do')]`
  `skip(small_list, :verb)`
  `answer = small_list.first.word`
  `assert_equal(answer,nil)`
 `end` Raise the same error.

Comment: If you want to adjust your test to your code, the correct assertion would be `assert_equal([], small_list)` ;-) ... and not calculate `nil.word`.

Comment: Gotcha, I changed the test as you suggested but the same error is still coming up.